# Error while optimizing in R

Tags: r, optimization, solver, minimize

I am creating two functions f(i) and f(j) and I want to  find the value of i and j simultaneously such that the difference f(i) -f(j) is minimized.
However on running the code below I am getting an error.

I have two functions with parameter i and j as below

```
bu1<- function(j){
sum(linkinc_lev1$gdp*(1/(1+ (linkinc_lev1$use_gro*(1+j/100))))
}

bu1<- function(j){
sum(linkinc_lev2$gdp*(1/(1+ (linkinc_lev2$use_gro*(1+i/100))))
}
```

Now I need to find the value of i and j simultaneously such that difference of above functions minimized.

I was trying like

```
f1<- function(j,i) abs(bu1(j)-td1(i))
ans_lev1<-optimize(f1, lower=-100, upper=100),
```

but getting error  `Error in td1(i) : argument "i" is missing, with no default`

Is there any way in R to minimize functions based on two parameters?

Comment: you have two functions bu1 ... but no td1. By the way what is `linkinc_lev1` ? A pot of jam, a brass plane?

Comment: haha..apologies, the second function is td1. linkinc_lev1 is just a dataframe name, shud have mentioned :)

Comment: does the below help? and can you `dput` your data?

Comment: I'm yet to check will get back to you soon. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, almost all optimizers work on parameter vectors.  You should modify your function to something like

```
f1<- function(param) abs(bu1(param[2])-td1(param[1]))
```

i.e. the function takes a single argument "param", and inside the function you fetch the values of interest out of it.

A note: if you use `abs()` you end up with a non-differentiable objective function.  You have to select an optimizer that can handle it (SANN and Nelder-Mead can, for instance).  I would rather do

```
f1 <- function(param) (bu1(param[2])-td1(param[1]))^2
```

still the same solution but now differentiable, and you can feed it to most optimizers.